# Email Notification for Workflow approvers

Tags: sharepoint-2007

MOSS 2007

I have a issue with workflow (out of box) email alerts. We get the email alert for a workflow intiator but not for an approver

Due date alerts are working fine, only the job immediate alerts are not coming,

When approver is trying to reassign the task to some person, even he dont receive any email for his new task.

pls suggest me on this issue.

all the settings are fine,

thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post your question here : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

i found in an other Forum that,
Tasks, project tasks, and issue-tracking lists can send e-mail to people when items are assigned to them if outgoing mail is enabled.  Other lists can support the same functionality, but you'd have to do something custom.  You could create a notification workflow in SharePoint Designer to handle this.
thanks